# What could be causing this crash?

Tags: c++, gcc

I have a C++ program (GCC) and when I add one or more int members to an abstract base class, the program starts crashing. In the case I've examined, it seems that by adding this member, a member in a derived class quits getting initialized (or gets stomped on at some point). If I add more members, it starts (not) working different. This is all really odd because the member is never used anywhere. I can comment out that one line and the program recompile just fine and runs without error.

The whole program is ~3KLOC and would be very hard to strip down.

*I'm totally at a loss as to where to start looking. Any Ideas?*

---

### Update

I found the issue: `free`-ing `malloc`-ed memory and `delete`-ing `new`-ed memory is not safe in the same program.

Comment: We are also at a loss since we have no idea what your code looks like. Post the abstract class. Post a derived class. Post the line of code where it crashes. Post something!

Comment: Have you built all other dependent binaries? For example, if you are windows are using something like multiple Dlls and your base class is one dll and the derived in another then you need to build both.

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could supply the smallest program that still reproduces the fault.  I understand this could be quite some effort on your part.

Comment: Stop downvoting the question!  This is a classic C++ problem.

Comment: @quamran: If I could do that and post something under 100LOC I could almost for sure answer the question my self because it would give me a good idea where to start looking. and *that* is all I'm looking for.

Comment: @BCS: So that would mean that you could solve the problem by following quamrana's suggestion!

Comment: @divo: that presupposes I can do quamran's suggestion. (I rather suspect that there are much easier ways to get this fixed)

Comment: About the update, I suppose it could be a  problem on some platforms, but I've never had problems doing both malloc/free and new/delete in the same program (the joys of using old libraries).  Of course, malloc/delete or new/free could cause a lot of issues...

Comment: How did you find the problem in the end? I too am surprised at the result unless, as @cjhuitt mentions, that it was a mismatched pairing.

Comment: @cjhuitt: I only `malloc`ed char* and only `delete`ed objects so unless I got something wrong in the wiring (and while I could have, I don't think I did)... ---- @Troubadour: I was talking about the bug to a friend (asking about how to use Valgrind) and the mixed malloc/new issue came up and he pointed out that it can be unsafe. I yanked the malloc and the program started running again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Off the top of my head, without seeing any code (see comments on your question) I would suggest a rogue pointer which normally stomps on something you don't notice, but introducing a new member makes it stomp on something you do notice.

Try adding members of different sizes, or more (unused) `int` members, or maybe a string in the form: `const char xxx[50];` to reserve more space.

Comment: Now this is interesting: adding a few more int changes the mode of failure. This warrants looking into...

Comment: ...with valgrind if your class instance is allocated on the heap. It might be slow but it'll be far quicker than a human squinting at bit patterns in their debugger trying to figure out what's doing the stomping. It'll just give you the complete stack when it happens.

Answer (score 7):

99 times out of 100 I find that if you change the data structure of a class and you start getting weird crashes then the build dependencies are not quite right i.e. you need to rebuild something that for some reason is not getting rebuilt.

If it's not a major pain to *completely* clean and rebuild your *entire* project then I would give that a go and then we can rule this answer out.

Comment: That was my first thought once I found where the crash was. No dice.

Answer (score 4):

A little more information about the crash would be helpful, as there are mulitple ways a program can crash. However, the first thing I do on Linux if I suspect it could be a memory error is to run the program through [Valgrind (Memcheck)](http://valgrind.org/) and see what it can tell me.

Also as a shot in the dark, is your build system generating dependencies correctly? One possibility is that your modifying the abstract class but not recompiling all the source files  which depend on the abstract class, which could be problematic.

Comment: I'm using the make remakes a makefile thing so I think the dependencies are correct. Also, if I do a full rebuild it doesn't go away. :(

Comment: Since we now know it's not a stale build issue I would go with the valgrind approach suggested here because the next logical thing to test is whether your program only _appears_ to work when the extra members are not present. Running valgrind is straightforward but can be hideously slow so make sure you know how to take the shortest route to the crash :)

Comment: the crash happens in about 0.1s so speed shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try running your program in gdb.

```
gdb your_executable
```

Then hit 'r' then enter
when your code crashes you can hit 'bt' then enter to see the offending line of code.

Comment: under one case it gives me a bad stack with `strlen` and `printf` on the top, under another, it gives me some place in `list.h` in `yyparse` in main (I think this is another corrupt stack as main doesn't call `yyparse`)

Comment: can you copy the back trace and put it in a comment?  But my initial thought is that somewhere along the way your not safely up casting or down casting a derived object.

Answer (score 1):

After you changed the class did you re-compile all the source?

If you only re-compiled the base or derived class (not sure where you put the new int) then all the other objects have the wrong size for your class. You need to delete all the object files and re-build them.